# GitHub GraphQL API: only get issues that have over n comments

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-api-v4

I'm playing with GitHub GraphQL API in order to get the list of most commented issues (say, comments > 100) across most popular repositories.

Here's the search query that I'm starting from:

```
search(query: "stars:>10000 fork:false pushed:>2020-01-01 is:public mirror:false archived:false", type: REPOSITORY)
```

So far so good, except that it looks like this high level GitHub search doesn't provide any filters related to issues and comments: I can't filter out repos that don't have issues at all, nor can I set a threshold for the number of comments.

Then I try to see if there's a filter specific to the list of issues, but it seems that the `filterBy` for `issues` doesn't provide any way to filter by comments or related activity:

```
    search(query: "stars:>10000 fork:false pushed:>2020-01-01 is:public mirror:false archived:false", type: REPOSITORY) {
    repositoryCount
    nodes {
        ... on Repository {
            issues(first: 100, filterBy: { <!-- Nothing useful here--> }, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}) {
                totalCount
                edges {
                    node {
                        title
                        comments {
                            totalCount
                        }
                        id
                        number
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious, or do I really need to get *all* issues from the API and then process the result locally to strip away issues that have less than 100 comments?